# How to set CSS rule only for iPhone browsers without JS?

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, safari

I need to set the specific CSS rule only for iPhone browsers: CriOS and Safari. Can I do this inside the CSS-file without using any JS-code?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can not.
But if the iPhone is not essential and screen resolution is ok, you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

This is not a complete iPhone solution, the screen resolution also works on other mobile browser, but you can get a suitable performance in this way.

**iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 6 in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 6 in portrait**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
iPhone 6 Plus Media Queries
iPhone 6 Plus in portrait & landscape
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 6 Plus in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 6 Plus in portrait**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPhone 5 & 5S Media Queries
iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 5 & 5S in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPhone 2G, 3G, 4, 4S Media Queries
iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 2G-4S in landscape**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

**iPhone 2G-4S in portrait**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

**iPhone 5 Resolution**

```
Screen Width = 320px (CSS Pixels)
Screen Height = 568px (CSS Pixels)

Screen Width = 640px (Actual Pixels)
Screen Height = 1136px (Actual Pixels)

Device-pixel-ratio: 2
```

**iPhone 4/4S Resolution**

```
Screen Width = 320px (CSS Pixels)
Screen Height = 480px (CSS Pixels)

Screen Width = 640px (Actual Pixels)
Screen Height = 960px (Actual Pixels)

Device-pixel-ratio: 2
```

**iPhone 2G/3G/3GS Resolution**

```
 Screen Width = 320px (CSS Pixels)
 Screen Height = 480px (CSS Pixels)

 Screen Width = 320px (Actual Pixels)
 Screen Height = 480px (Actual Pixels)

 Device-pixel-ratio: 1
```